# ElasticSearch filtering by field1 THEN field2 THEN take max of field3

Tags: elasticsearch

I am struggling to get the information that I need from ElasticSearch.

My log statements are like this:

```
field1: Example
field2: Example2
field3: Example3
```

I would like to search a timeframe (using last 24 hours) to find all data that has `this` in `field1` and `that` in `field2`.

There then may be multiple `this.that.[field3]` entries, so I want to only return the maximum of that field.

In fact, in my data, field3 is actually the key of the entry.

What is the best way of retrieving the information I need? I have managed to get the results returned using aggs, but the data is in buckets, and I am only interested in the data with the max value of field3.

I have added an example of the query that I am looking to do: https://jsonblob.com/54535d49e4b0d117eeaf6bb4

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "agg_129": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "CarName: Toyota": {
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "CarName: Toyota"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg_130": {
          "filters": {
            "filters": {
              "Attribute: TimeUsed": {
                "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                    "query": "Attribute: TimeUsed"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_131": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "size": 0,
                "order": {
                  "_count": "desc"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "2014-10-27T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "lte": "2014-10-28T23:59:59.999Z"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, that example above is showing only those that have CarName = Toyota and Attribute = TimeUsed.

My data is as follows:

There are x number of cars `CarName` and each car has y number of `Attributes` and each of those `Attributes` have a document with a timestamp.

To begin with, I was looking for a query for CarName.Attribute.timestamp (latest), however, if I am able to use just ONE query to get the latest timestamp for EVERY attribute for EVERY CarName, then that would decrease query calls from ~50 to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a ElasticSearch v1.3+, you can add a `top_hits` aggregation with parameter `size:1` and descending sort on the `field3` value.

This will return the whole document with maximum value on the field, as you wish.

This [example in the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#_example_2) might do the trick.

Edit:

Ok, it seems you don't need the whole document, but only the maximum timestamp value. You can use a `max` aggregation instead of using a `top_hits` one.

The following query (not tested) should give you the maximum `timestamp` value for each top 10 `Attribute` value of each `CarName` top 10 value, in only one request.

`terms` aggregation is like a GROUP BY clause, and you should not have to query 50 times to retrieve the values of each CarName/Attribute combination : this is the point of nesting a `terms` aggregation for `Attribute` in the `CarName` aggregation.

Note that, to work properly, the `CarName` and `Attribute` fields should be `not_analyzed`. If it's not the case, you will have "funny" results in your buckets. The problem (and possible solution) is very well described [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/aggregations-and-analysis.html#aggregations-and-analysis).

Feel free to change the `size` parameter of the `terms` aggregation to fit to your case.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_carnames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "CarName",
        "size": 10
      }, 
      "aggs": {
        "by_attribute": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Attribute",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max_timestamp": {
              "max": {
                "field": "@timestamp"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "2014-10-27T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "lte": "2014-10-28T23:59:59.999Z"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Tom, thank you for the help. I have updated my original post with the query that I am using as I can't seem to be able to get the aggs to work. Would you mind having a quick look to see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Thank you very much Tom, I actually managed to get it working minutes before you posted the answer. I just had issues with my aggs nesting. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for though. Thanks for taking the time :-)

Comment: Just quickly Tom, is there any way to do relative date in ElasticSearch (i.e. today) instead of putting in gte and lte?

Comment: You can use `now` in your dates (e.g. `now-1h`). Check [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#date-math) for information about date math.